# How can I import multiple fasta-files from multiple subfolders into a list of lists

Tags: r, list, import, fasta

I have several subfolders ("C1", "C2", "C3") and each of these subfolders contain four fasta-files.
I would like to import this so that each subfolder is an element of a list and each element should then contain four separate elements, one for each fasta-file in the according subfolder.

Until now, I only imported multiple fasta-files directly into a list using:

```
library(Biostrings)
temp = list.files(pattern="*.fasta")
myfiles = lapply(temp, readDNAStringSet)
```

But I don't really know how to read them from multiple subfolders and use these subfolders as superior list element.
I hope it's understandable what I mean..

Comment: `list.files` has a `recursive=TRUE` option that will search into subfolders.

Comment: I tried that, but then I get a list with, for example 8 elements (2 subfolders with 4 fasta-files each). However, I would like to get a list with two lists (subfolders) containing 4 elements each (fasta-files)