# Read files from Multiple subfolders as a list

Tags: r, list

I have a Main directory with several sub folders consisting of raster files. I would like to read all the files in the sub folders but I don't want them all together. Instead I want them in a list where the first element of the list would be all the files from the first subfolder, second element- all files from the second subfolder and so on. I already found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633551/how-can-i-import-multiple-fasta-files-from-multiple-subfolders-into-a-list-of-li) which was similar to my problem but there wasnt any answer. I know you could use list.files with recursive to read all files within a subfolder like

```
dat.files  <- list.files(path="C:/Main dir",
                         recursive=T,
                         pattern="*.tif$"
                         ,full.names=T)
```

but this brings a single character vector of all files instead of lists of character vectors depending on the subfolder position like [ chr vector 1st folder, chr vector 2nd folder,.....so on]

Is there a way to do this or has this already been answered? Any suggestions or helps are welcomed and appreciated.

**EDITED**
Based on @stefan s suggestion, I did it by two steps which worked. I will add how I did it

```
dir.files  <- list.dirs(path="Main dir", recursive = F) 
dat.files <- lapply(dir.files, list.files)
```

Comment: You could do that in two steps. 1. Use `list.dirs` to get the subfolders. 2. Loop over the subfolders using e.g. `lapply` to get the files.

Answer (score 0):

The following function, untested, first gets the sub-directories in vector `d` and then loops through these sub-dirs and gets the filenames matching `pattern`. Then it uses a double `lapply` loop to read in the data with the function passed in argument `reader`. The ellipses (the dots argument) can be used to pass further arguments on to `reader`.

```
read_files_subdir <- function(path = '.', pattern = NULL, reader = scan, ...){
  reader = match.fun(reader)
  d <- list.dirs(path = path, full.names = TRUE)
  fls_list <- lapply(d, list.files, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE)
  lapply(fls_list, function(fls){
    lapply(fls, reader, ...)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciate it